# XML file does not have style sheet associated

Tags: xml, xslt

When I run the webpage using .xml in my browser, it just displays the code and the following statement:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

This is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href=wonders.xsl" ?>

<seven_wonders>
    <wonder>    
        <name>Great Pyramid Of Giza</name>
        <location>Giza Necropolis, Egypt</location>
        <builder>Egyptians</builder>
        <constructed>2584-2561 BC</constructed>
    </wonder>
    <wonder>    
        <name>Hanging Gardens of Babylon</name>
        <location>Hillah, Babylon Province, Iraq or Nineveh, Nineveh Province, Iraq</location>
        <builder>Babylonians</builder>
        <constructed>c. 600 BC</constructed>
    </wonder>
    <wonder>    
        <name>Temple of Artemis at Ephesus</name>
        <location>Selcuk, Izmir Province, Turkey</location>
        <builder>Lydians, Greeks</builder>
        <constructed>c. 550 BC</constructed>
    </wonder>
    <wonder>    
        <name>Statue of Zeus at Olympia</name>
        <location>Olympia, Greece</location>
        <builder>Greeks</builder>
        <constructed>466-435 BC</constructed>
    </wonder>
    <wonder>    
        <name>Mausoleum at Halicarnassus</name>
        <location>Bodrum, Turkey</location>
        <builder>Carians, Greeks</builder>
        <constructed>351 BC</constructed>
    </wonder>
    <wonder>    
        <name>Colossus of Rhodes</name>
        <location>Rhodes, Greece</location>
        <builder>Greeks</builder>
        <constructed>292-280 BC</constructed>
    </wonder>
    <wonder>    
        <name>Lighthouse of Alexandria</name>
        <location>Alexandria, Egypt</location>
        <builder>Ptolemaic Egypt, Greeks</builder>
        <constructed>c. 280 BC</constructed>
    </wonder>                       
</seven_wonders>
```

And this is my .xsl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes" standalone="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
   <body>
    <head>
       <title>Seven Wonders of the Ancient World</title>
    </head>
    <table border="2" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="3">
       <tr bgcolor="gray">
        <th><b>Name</b></th>
        <th><b>Location</b></th>
        <th><b>Builder</b></th>
        <th><b>Date of Construction</b></th>
       </tr>
       <xsl:for-each select="seven_wonders/wonder">
       <tr valign="top">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="location"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="builder"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="constructed"/></td>
       </tr>
       </xsl:for-each>
       <tr>
        <td><i>Resource</i></td>
        <td colspan="3"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Wonders_of_the_Ancient_World">http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Wonders_of_the_Ancient_World</a></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
   </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm relatively new to all of this, so if someone could please let me know what I'm doing wrong, I would really appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: You're missing a double quote after the equals: `href="`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the bug, after fixing it, document loaded and transformed just fine:

```
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes" standalone="yes" />
```

You need `method="html"`, otherwise IE thinks this is XML and formats it accordingly

[Here's a specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/), but otherwise you did it right.